# Tkinter GUI using images from site

Tags: python, tkinter

I am able to get the image to display in the GUI with Tkinter however I can not get this part of the code to work as I am trying to keep it all either under one .py file because it is easier for me to keep everything in one singular window.

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Holcomb Family/PycharmProjects/webscrapeTKINTER/venv/main4.py", line 32, in <module>
    run = MainWin(root)
    pil_img = Image.open(my_picture)
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

My code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *
from urllib.request import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("New Window")


class MainWin:
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master

    url1 = "https://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/lds/pc/global/images/itemicon/"
    url2 = "da/dad2c1875e87e7a7f1d02fce24f0bd0351cdda11.png?n5.45"
    pic_url = url1 + url2


    my_page = urlopen(pic_url)
    my_picture = io.BytesIO(my_page.read())
    pil_img = Image.open(my_picture)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)

    self.label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_img)
    self.label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


root = Tk()
run = MainWin(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your imports are messed up. Are you aware there is `tkinter.Image` as well, python thinks you are reffering to `tkinter.Image` as it is the last import. This is why you should not do `from x import *`. Move the import of `tkinter` to the top.

Comment: Could you have some other object called `Image` somewhere in your code? If yes do not unnecessarily import all symbols in the same namespace and use `import PIL` and `pil_img = PIL.Image.open(my_picture)`

Comment: Using wildcard imports link `from tkinter import *` is broadly considered a poor programming practice because it pollutes the namespace and can lead to hard-to-diagnose errors like you're encountering. Suggest you use `import tkinter as tk` instead.

Comment: I was able to fix this, thanks for the assist.  I was just trying the from tkinter import *; I usually just have it set for tk.